# intercept web traffic from visual studio xamarin for mac / iOS simulator

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, http-proxy

I know almost nothing about Visual Studio or Xamarin. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac 8.9.10. This isn't my code and I'm trying to understand it.

This app does REST requests to my server (rails) and I am trying to intercept them. I have my iOS Simulator set up so that network requests can pass thru Proxyman. This works fine for, say, Mobile Safari on the Simulator, or for an app that I write myself in Xcode. I thus believe I have a good handle on Proxyman usage and on the traffic I am trying to intercept.

However, when my app built from Visual Studio Xamarin does networking in the Simulator, nothing appears in Proxyman. I thought at first this might be because of my use of a localhost server for testing, but it is equally true for normal requests that really do go out on the Internet. Proxyman doesn't seem to see my app's traffic at all.

This makes me think there is something odd about the way Visual Studio / Xamarin itself configures iOS apps for networking. Is there? How do Mac users intercept web traffic from a Xamarin Visual Studio-built iOS app in the Simulator?

(And another thing: If I write my own iOS app to be intercepted by Proxyman, I have to enable NSArbitraryLoads in order to talk via http. But my Visual Studio Xamarin app doesn't have that in the Info.plist; yet it can talk via http. How can that be? Seems related.)

(This might be related: it seems Xamarin http requests really do evade the proxy somehow? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129748/how-do-i-make-http-requests-using-proxy-settings)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Proxyman, but I've done this in the past with Wireshark.  There shouldn't be anything related to Xamarin that makes it different than other apps in the simulator.

Comment: That's what's so weird @Jason. It's as if it's evading my proxy!

Comment: It sounds like you need reverse proxy capability (which isn't available in proxy man [yet](https://github.com/ProxymanApp/Proxyman/issues/447)). This way you point your app at the proxy (which acts like the actual web server) and it forwards the request to your actual web server (you need proxyman listening on a different port to your actual web service) Charles Proxy [has this capability](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/reverse-proxy/) but has limitations unless you buy it. You could probably also set up ngenix to do it for free, but it becomes a time/$ trade off

Comment: That should , of course, be [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/)

Comment: @Paulw11 Reverse proxy sounds right. It would certainly be doable from the Xamarin app point of view, ie I know what line of code to change to repoint at the middleman. I am mystified by Charles which is why I adopted Proxyman; however, I may be forced by this situation to try Charles again.

Comment: However @Paulw11 the thing is, I am already pointing the Xamarin app at localhost.proxyman.io which seems to _be_ a kind of reverse proxy already. So I remain somewhat mystified...

Comment: Have you set that address as the api endpoint (which would then operate as a reverse proxy to your actual web server)? Or have you configured that address as the proxy for your device (which it appears ignoring)?

Comment: As the endpoint. It works fine in the sense that communication is routed to my local server. But none of that traffic appears in proxyman. But it works fine for an angular app running a browser, so the approach works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233040/discussion-between-paulw11-and-matt).

Comment: I see now. The trouble is that localhost.proxyman.io is not a reverse proxy. It's just a DNS munger. A reverse proxy is a web server acting as a man in the middle. This is what is needed to intercept communication from apps that do http without regard for proxy settings. localhost.proxyman.io doesn't help with that.

Comment: @Paulw11 your comment, together with the links I supplied, constitute the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the lower level network stack itself that respects the system proxy settings; ideally network frameworks *should*, but it appears that Xamarin's does not.

`localhost.proxyman.io` is a DNS entry that points to localhost but it doesn't redirect the traffic through the proxy.

You need a something that can act as a reverse proxy - A service that looks to the client like your web service, but that redirects requests to your *actual* web service.  This feature is not [yet available in proxyman](https://github.com/ProxymanApp/Proxyman/issues/447).

You can use [Charles proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/reverse-proxy/) as an alternative.

Comment: Perfect-o-rama, thank you. Naturally I went with Charles despite its free-usage limitations, just to make sure I could see something, and sure enough, I did.